# ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized fix is causing errors

Tags: java

I had a line of code which is below.

```
List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList();
```

This caused the warning `ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E> should be parameterized`. I did some research and found these questions - [Collections of generics “Cannot instantiate the type ArrayList”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409756/collections-of-generics-cannot-instantiate-the-type-arraylist-extends-opdto) and [How can elements be added to a wildcard generic collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176446/how-can-elements-be-added-to-a-wildcard-generic-collection). So I constructed a `public List` which looked like the following.

```
public <T extends SortKey> List<T> sortKeys() {
    List<SortKey> keys = new ArrayList<SortKey>();
    keys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey( 0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    keys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey( 1, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    return keys;
}
```

However when I try to compile this code I get the error, `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<RowSorter.SortKey> to List<T>`. How can I fix this error?

---

*Note*
I also found the that the line of code, `List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();`, removes the warning but I do not understand why? I would appreciate if someone took the time to explain that or reference something which would allow me understand it.

---

**Edit**
Using the following code fixes the error.

```
public <T extends SortKey> List<T> sortKeys() {
    List<T> keys = new ArrayList<T>();
    keys.add((T) new RowSorter.SortKey( 0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    keys.add((T) new RowSorter.SortKey( 1, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
    return keys;
}
```

However new warning are produced which state `Type safety: Unchecked cast from RowSorter.SortKey to T`.

Comment: `T extends SortKey` tells the compiler the type must derive from `SortKey` (be a subtype), as opposed to actually being `SortKey`. Since your function returns `List<T extends SortKey>`, you cannot return a `List<SortKey>`. Since you are returning `keys` (which is a `List<SortKey>`), you are getting an error.

Comment: As for `List<? extends SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList()` giving an error, it's becayse you never specify the type argument, which makes it raw (same as ArrayList<Object>). Since the variable specifies the type argument, the value must aswell (or at least infer it). Doing `new ArrayList<>()` allows inference to specify the type

Comment: Why is your method generic? Why don't you just return a `List<SortKey>`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Just subbed that in. It fixes all. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, you're missing the generic braces on `new ArrayList()` -> `new ArrayList<>()`.

For the second question, you're trying to use SortKey (which doesn't extend from SortKey, of course) as the list type.

Not sure why you're storing them like that, though, because you can store subclasses by the superclass type.

Comment: "Generic braces" The correct term is a [diamond operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7).

Comment: The diamond operator was implemented in JDK 7, denoting the ability to leave the braces for generics empty for the compiler to refer the type. In this case, I could've substituted but didn't feel like it was the correct terminology for mentioning the braces as a whole.

Comment: @bcsb1001 The correct term is actually "*angle brackets*" as per the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2). AFAIK, the spec never refers to them as diamond operators.